# How many books are there in Esperanto?

Tags: culture, literature

I felt pretty motivated about reading Esperanto literature, especially after finding the [baza legolisto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/154/is-there-an-esperanto-literary-canon), and thought "I'll cover the basics in a year!".  After reading [this article](http://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/five-periods-of-esperanto-literature/) I felt a bit floored - and therefore my question how many books there are in Esperanto.

Comment: Could someone who voted by question down tell me why?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the fiction published in Esperanto consists of translations. If you mean books containing fiction *originally* written in Esperanto, then there aren't so many: about 200 novels have been published, and 400 volumes of short stories, and some of these books are very short. We are still at the stage at which a very determined person with a lot of money could conceivably read all of them. However, the quality is uneven, so it is a good idea to start with other people's recommendations. Of the novels, about two-thirds date from after 1980. Since then the rate has been about 3½ per year. You can find a detailed list on [Sten Johansson's website](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/index.html).

Reading fiction, both original and translated, is a good way to get comfortable with Esperanto. And it is advisable to keep a pocket dictionary on hand to look up words, as that is one of the most efficient methods of expanding vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

[La Katalogo de UEA](http://katalogo.uea.org/) has about 7461 titles (or 7262, see below), if I managed to count them correctly.

---

*NOTE:* It doesn't allow just listing all titles and requires searching by some criteria, so I tried in two ways:

1. I first picked titles with price of less than 1€ (361) and then with price of more than 1€ (7100), which makes 7461, assuming there is no overlap or missing titles.
2. I selected all titles published after year 1887 (duh), which shows 7262 titles.

In any case, there are more than 7000 books there.

Answer (score 1):

I had read that there was a library of books translated and written in Esperanto by Montagu Butler. His library is listed first in this Wikipedia article of all books/library that are written in Esperanto.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_library

Comment: Bonvenon al Stack Exchange, Sparkfist! I don't think he made all of that himself, but the library seems to have been named after him. Thank you!